# Преобразование строки чисел в список этих чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, списки, итераторы

Как преобразовать объект строки чисел в объект списка чисел,чтобы эти числа были через запятую?  Дана строка:  '2468375169'  Результат: [2,4,6,8,3,7,5,1,6,9]

Comment: list(map(int, list(s)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = '2468375169'
[(int(i)) for i in s]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 7, 5, 1, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = '2468375169'
lst = list(map(int, s))
print(lst)
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 7, 5, 1, 6, 9]
```